# Spyder runfile from other script

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to use runfile from within a script in Spyder.
When I do so, I get this error:

```
KeyError: '__file__'
```

How can I avoid this error?

Extra info:
I have previously imported other scripts as modules and run them accordingly, but I want to have the flexibility to run scripts individually (specifying input arguments in the scripts themselves) or call them from other scripts (specifying arguments when calling them).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) I don't think this is possible with the current design of `runfile`, sorry.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I see. Is there any other way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You could use the `%run` magic of IPython, I think, instead of `runfile`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how this can be done. I have two short python programs, controlled by a script. Both programs, `runfile_a.py` and `runfile_b.py` contain:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(__file__.split("\\")[-1], __name__)
```

The script contains:

```
# Paths edited
runfile('C:/Python/runfile_a.py', wdir='C:/Python')
runfile('C:/Python/runfile_b.py', wdir='C:/Python')
```

Output from script execution in Spyder:

```
In [11]: runfile('C:/Python/runfile_tst_ab.py', wdir='C:/Python')
runfile_a.py __main__
runfile_b.py __main__
```

From the output, I can see that each program was executed within an
environment with its own `__file__`.

The code for the `runfile()` method in Spyder is listed here on Github:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/spyder/plugins/console/utils/interpreter.py.